# Javascript calculate 19% taxes from parseFloat value total to pay

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I need to calculate the total taxes from the total price to pay including the taxes, the tax rate is 19% so the correct calculation is for example

```
total to pay = 1000 the taxes must be 160
```

Why? Because 840 + 19% gives you the total price to pay = 1000 so you know the taxes of 1000 including taxes are not 190 with 19% rate but 160.

To calculate it with autofill the input I am using javascript like this to autofill many inputs

```
totaltaxes.value = parseInt((parseFloat(totaltopay.value)*19)/100);}
```

The problem is that I keep getting 190 as result of the 19% taxes and it must be 160.

Anyone have a formula to do this or idea how to calculate it? It is the 19% of the total price to pay including the taxes in the total price

Comment: In that case, there are a lot of single people all of a sudden. Hint: Probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the total tax :

```
parseInt(totaltopay.value)*0.19/1.19
```

Comment: working perfect 
totaltaxes.value = parseInt(parseFloat(totaltopay.value) * (0.19/1.19));}

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a math problem than a javascript problem.

But, here's the solution anyway:

Your `totaltopay` value includes the tax, hence it is 1+(tax_percentage/100) times more than the amount to be paid.

You need to be doing `parseInt(totaltopay.value/1.19)` to get the amount to be paid.

Thus, the tax amount would be

`(totaltopay.value - (totaltopay.value/1.19) = (totaltopay.value*0.19/1.19)`

That is, 
`totaltaxes.value = parseInt((parseFloat(totaltopay.value)*19)/119);`

Comment: Sorry. I had initially answered for the amount to be paid value. Updated my answer.